# Dreamweaver CS5's Subversion Integration - is there any SVN addon for Dreamweaver?

Tags: svn, dreamweaver

Dreamweaver CS5 is supporting SVN up to version 1.6.6, meaning that all later svn formats are not supported and the Dreamweaver is returning errors that they cannot update the SVN so the internal svn integration is useless.

1. Does anybody know about any 3rd party SVN addon for Dreamweaver, pls?
2. Is there a way just to upgrade the files SVN used by the Dreamweaver, i.e. in "c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5\configuration\VersionControl\SVNPlugin166"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVN integration in Dreamweaver has always been...poor (feel free to substitute stronger language).  There is no good third-party add-in and there is no way to update it.